# Adding in a variable via route with static route laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I want to be able to add a variable to a route that directs to a controller.

The only way I've seen it done is if the route itself is dynamic. However, in my case, I want a static url that will send a static variable to a controller. The reason for which is that there will be two static routes that will use the same controller in a different way via variables.

I am having trouble finding this in the documentation.

All I have found is this

```
Route::get('posts/{post}/comments/{comment}', function ($postId, $commentId) {
```

I want to do the same but have {comment} and {post} but two variables is sent to the controllers.

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't use one route with a variable? That's what it's meant to do. Somewhere in your app, you probably have a logic which determines which value to pass, so why would you have two routes?

Comment: so basically I should make the logic to include only the two I want and give an error on the all the urls i don't want?

Comment: Well, if you are the one controlling those urls, yes...You can do some simple validation if you want, call findOrFail, or just whitelist those values, validate and throw 404 manually...But definitely no need to create two routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forexample:

```
Route::get('posts/{post}/comments/{comment}', ['as'=> 'viewComment', 'uses'=>'PostController@viewComment']);
```

Controller:

```
    public function viewComment ($post, $comment)
    {
        dd($post.'/'.$comment);
    }
```